# ArcGIS tool which shows all cells a point flows into?

Tags: watershed, flow, flow-accumulation, flow-map

Is there a tool that is effectively the inverse of flow accumulation of a pour point - as in, if I have a specific point that is the site of potential pollution, is there a tool which will show all cells that are downstream of it?

Comment: Please edit your post to include your version of Arc, and a detailed description of your data. Screenshots are often useful.  Also, what have you tried so far, and what were the results?

Comment: Cost path does it, but in some versions you need to convert flow direction into backlink raster